# How to get path to object files with CMake for both multiconfiguration generator and makefile based ones?

Tags: windows, cmake

I would like to generate a [module definition file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28d6s79h.aspx) based on all symbols available in object files in dynamic fashion (think of [GTKMM](http://www.gtkmm.org/en/)'s [gendef](https://github.com/GNOME/gtkmm/blob/master/MSVC_Net2013/gendef/gendef.cc)).

For this, I would like to [`add_custom_command`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events) for `PRE_LINK` step of a target. However, it looks like there is no *easy* way to get path to all object files with CMake that would work for plain makefiles as well as for multi-configuration generators like Visual Studio.

Right now, I have the following

```
add_custom_command(TARGET tgt PRE_LINK
COMMAND gendef ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tgt.def $<TARGET_FILE_NAME:tgt> ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/$<$<BOOL:${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}>:${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}>/tgt.dir/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}/*.obj
)
```

However this is quite awkward and bulky as I have to use [generator expression](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) in my opinion. Is there a better way to achieve this effect, i.e. call a certain external program for each build configuration?

Is it a CMake bug (feature?) that for plain makefiles, all object files go to `CMakeFiles/tgt.dir` folder while for multiconfiguration generators all goes to a *sibling* of CMakeFiles, i.e. `tgt.dir/$<CONFIG>`? Did I miss some simple variable that would point me to the right place directly?

Comment: I had a similar request myself in the past. And as far as I know there is no easy way to get the list of object files. I assume you were aware of ["CMake: Is there an elegant way to get list of object files participating into a library?"](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/Is-there-an-elegant-way-to-get-list-of-object-files-participating-into-a-library-tp6071240.html). Have you tried the intermediate static library approach? Or you could think of object libraries and support [0016041: Add support for $<TARGET_OBJECTS:objLib> in add_custom_command()](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=16041).

Answer (score 1):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

Makefile projects generated by CMake have a totally different internal structure then solutions/projects generated for Visual Studio. I think this is neither a bug nor a feature, those structures are just optimized for their usecases.

And as far as I know there is no easy CMake internal way to get the list of object files or the path to the intermediate files directory with e.g. reading a target property.

So I have taken your code example and have done some testing for alternatives with CMake 3.3.2 using `Visual Studio 14 2015` and `NMake Makefiles` generators.

**Alternatives**

1. One related discussion on the CMake mailing list named ["CMake: Is there an elegant way to get list of object files participating into a library?"](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/Is-there-an-elegant-way-to-get-list-of-object-files-participating-into-a-library-td6071240.html) does suggest using an intermediate static library:

   ```
   add_library(tgtlib STATIC tgt.c)
   add_custom_command(
       OUTPUT tgt.def
       COMMAND gendef tgt.def $<TARGET_FILE_NAME:tgt> $<TARGET_FILE:tgtLib> 
   )
   file(WRITE dummy.c "")
   add_library(tgt SHARED dummy.c tgt.def)
   target_link_libraries(tgt tgtlib)
   ```
2. You could add build environment specific elements to your `PRE_LINK` step:

   ```
   if(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
       set(_obj_files "$(IntermediateOutputPath)*.obj")
   else()
       set(_obj_files "$?")
   endif()
   add_custom_command(
       TARGET MainProject 
       PRE_LINK
       COMMAND gendef tgt.def $<TARGET_FILE_NAME:tgt> ${_obj_files}
   )
   ```

**References**

- [NMAKE: Filename Macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbes8ded.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

List of compiled object files could be extracted via `$<TARGET_OBJECTS>` [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_OBJECTS). While its primary purpose was to extract object files from OBJECT library target, it actually works for all other library and executable targets:

```
add_executable(main main.cpp foo.c)

add_custom_target(list_objects ALL
  COMMAND echo "Objects:" $<TARGET_OBJECTS:main>
  VERBATIM
  )
```

Upon building it would print

```
Objects: /home/tester/tests/cmake/build/CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o;/home/tester/tests/cmake/build/CMakeFiles/main.dir/foo.c.o
```

---

Note, that generator expressions cannot be printed via `message` command.
But they may appear as arguments for some other commands, which have documented usage of generator expressions. For more details about printing generator expressions, see [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51353110/how-do-i-output-the-result-of-a-generator-expression-in-cmake).