# How can I express PGO dependencies in CMake 3.7 and higher?

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, pgo

I have a C++ program that I'm building with Clang 3.9's profile-guided optimization feature.  Here's what's supposed to happen:

1. I build the program with instrumentation enabled.
2. I run that program, creating a file with profile-data: `prof.raw`.
3. I use `llvm-profdata` to convert `prof.raw` to a new file, `prof.data`.
4. I create a new build of that same program, with a few changes:

   - When compiling each .cpp file to a .o file, I use the compiler flag `-fprofile-use=prof.data`.
   - When linking the executable, I also specify `-fprofile-use`.

I have a Gnu Makefile for this, and it works great.  My problem arises now that I'm trying to port that Makefile to CMake (3.7, but I could upgrade ).  I need the solution to work with (at least) the Unix Makefiles generator, but ideally it would work for all generators.

In CMake, I've defined two executable targets: `foo-gen` and `foo-use`:

- When `foo-gen` is executed, it creates the `prof.raw` file.
- I use `add_custom_command` to create a rule to create `prof.data` from `prof.raw`.

**My problem** is that I can't figure out how to tell CMake that each of the object files depended upon by `foo-use` has a dependency on the file `prof.data`.

- The most-promising idea I had was to (1) find a way to enumerate all of the `.o` files upon which `foo-use` depenends, and then (2) iterate over each of those `.o` files, calling [`add_dependency`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_dependencies.html) for each one.

  The problem with this approach is I can't find an idiomatic way, in my CMakeLists.txt file, to enumerate the list of object files upon which an executable depends.  This might [be an open problem with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884856/how-to-get-path-to-object-files-with-cmake-for-both-multiconfiguration-generator).
- I also considered using [`set_source_files_properties`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/set_source_files_properties.html) to set the [`OBJECT_DEPENDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_sf/OBJECT_DEPENDS.html) property on each of my `.cpp` files used by `foo-use`, adding `prof.data` to that property's list.

  The problem with this (AFAICT) is that each of my `.cpp` files is used to create two different `.o` files: one for `foo-gen` and one for `foo-use`.  I want the `.o` files that get linked into `foo-use` to have this compile-time dependency on `prof.data`; but the `.o` files that get linked into `foo-gen` must *not* have a compile-time dependency on `prof.data`.

  And AFAIK, `set_source_files_properties` doesn't let me set the `OBJECT_DEPENDS` property to have one of two values, contingent on whether `foo-gen` or `foo-use` is the current target of interest.

Any suggestions for a clean(ish) way to make this work?

Comment: Can you please add a [mcve]? Some CMake code would help to suggest something.

Comment: @Florian, It is hard to add example code because cmake simple doesn't seem to have any sane way to do this in a single project. I'm trying to solve exact same issue and simplest solution feels like using generator expression in OBJECT_DEPENDS (not supported). I don't think one can use $<TARGET_OBJECTS:tgt> for add_dependencies which seems to be only sane way to access object list. Potential other solution a) double project system where main user invoked project forwards settings to second pgo project compiling same settings again. b) Just replace build based system with shell script.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267352/cmake-compile-a-program-twice-in-a-row) your question? If it does, it's a shame because this question is slightly older and better written.

Comment: update: I believe [the accepted answer in that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45268804/11107541) contains the very problem this question is trying to solve: it doesn't make each source file re-compile if the training profile data has changed.

Answer (score 3):

#### Discussion on author's idea #1

> The most-promising idea I had was to (1) find a way to enumerate all of the `.o` files upon which `foo-use` depenends, and then (2) iterate over each of those `.o` files, calling `add_dependency` for each one.

This shouldn't work according to the documentation for [`add_dependencies`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html), which states:

> Makes a top-level  depend ***on other top-level targets*** to ensure that they build before  does.

Ie. You can't use it to make a target depend on *files*- only on *other targets*.

#### Discussion on author's idea #2

> I also considered using set_source_files_properties to set the `OBJECT_DEPENDS` property on each of my `.cpp` files used by `foo-use`, adding `prof.data` to that property's list.
>
> The problem with this (AFAICT) is that each of my `.cpp` files is used to create two different `.o` files: one for `foo-gen` and one for `foo-use`. I want the `.o` files that get linked into `foo-use` to have this compile-time dependency on `prof.data`; but the `.o` files that get linked into `foo-gen` must not have a compile-time dependency on `prof.data`.
>
> And AFAIK, `set_source_files_properties` doesn't let me set the `OBJECT_DEPENDS` property to have one of two values, contingent on whether `foo-gen` or `foo-use` is the current target of interest.

In the comment section, you mentioned that you could solve this if `OBJECT_DEPENDS` supported generator expressions, but it doesn't. As a side note, there [is an issue ticket tracking this on the CMake gitlab repo](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22034). You can go give it a  thumbs up and describe your use-case for their reference.

In the comments section you also mentioned a possible solution to this:

> Potential other solution a) double project system where main user invoked project forwards settings to second pgo project compiling same settings again.

You can actually put this into the CMake project via `ExternalProject` so that it becomes part of the generated buildsystem: Make the top-level project *include itself* as an external project. The external project can be passed a cache variable to configure it to be the `-gen` version, and the top-level can be the `-use` version.

Speaking from experience, this is a whole other rabbit hole of long CMake-documentation-reading and finicking sessions if you have never manually invoked or done anything with `ExternalProject` before, so that answer might belong with a new question dedicated to it.

This can solve the problem of not having generator expressions in `OBJECT_DEPENDS`, but if you want to have multi-config for the top-level project and that some of the configs in the multi-config config not be for PGO, then you will be back to square one.

### Proposed Solution

Here's what I've found works to make sources re-compile when profile data changes:

1. To the custom command which runs the training executable and produces and re-formats the training data, add another `COMMAND` which produces a c++ header file containing a timestamp in a comment.
2. Include that header in all sources which you want to re-compile if the training has been re-run.

If you want to support non-PGO builds, wrap the timestamp header in a header which checks that it exists with `__has_include` and only includes it if it exists.

I'm pretty sure with this approach, CMake doesn't do the dependency checking of TUs on the profile data, and instead, it's the generated buildsystem's header-dependency tracking which does that work. The rationale for including a timestamp comment in the header file instead of just "touch"ing it to change the timestamp in the filesystem is that the generated buildsystem might detect changes by file contents instead of by the filesystem timestamp.

#### All the shortcomings of the proposed solution

The painfully obvious weakness of this approach is that you need to add a header include to all the .cpp files that you want to check for re-compilation. There are several problems that can spawn from this (from least to most egregious):

1. You might not like it from an aesthetics standpoint.
2. It certainly opens up a hole for human-error in forgetting to include the header for new .cpp files. <strike>I don't know how to solve that.</strike> Some compilers have a flag that you can use to include a file in every source file, such as [GCC's `-include` flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) and [MSVC's `/FI` flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fi-name-forced-include-file). You can then just add this flag to a CMake target using `target_compile_options(<target> PRIVATE "SHELL:-include <path>")`
3. You might not be able to change some of the sources that you need to re-compile, such as sources from third-party static libraries that your library depends on. There may be workarounds if you're using `ExternalProject` by doing something with the `patch` step, but I don't know.

For my personal project, #1 and #2 are acceptable, and #3 happens to not be an issue. You can take a look at how I'm doing things [there](https://github.com/david-fong/okiidoku) if you're interested.

#### Toward a standard PGO CMake module

See https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/19273

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of doing this is to go through the configure+build workflow twice.

The first time, you create the initial build tree and build with both `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` set to a value containing `-fprofile-generate`. Then you run the unit tests you're interested in running. For instance, you might have a CTest label named `performance`.

Then the second time, you reconfigure in place with `-fprofile-use` instead. Then you can build, run *all* of your tests and install or package.

This can all be orchestrated without *too* much hassle using CMake presets, which I'll show in a minute.

First off, here's the `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(pgo-test)

enable_testing()

add_executable(example main.cpp)

add_test(NAME runs COMMAND example)
add_test(NAME perf COMMAND example --perf)

set_tests_properties(
  perf
  PROPERTIES
  LABELS "performance"
)
```

This is the easy part. My `main.cpp` is just a basic "Hello, world!", provided here for ease of copy/paste.

```
#include <iostream>
int main () { std::cout << "Hello, world!\n"; return 0; }
```

Now we can write the `CMakePresets.json`. I'd consult the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) before reading this.

```
{
  "version": 6,
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "base",
      "hidden": true,
      "binaryDir": "build",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_C_FLAGS": "$env{PGO_FLAGS}",
        "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS": "$env{PGO_FLAGS}"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "pgo-gen",
      "inherits": "base",
      "environment": { "PGO_FLAGS": "-fprofile-generate" }
    },
    {
      "name": "pgo-use",
      "inherits": "base",
      "environment": { "PGO_FLAGS": "-fprofile-use" }
    }
  ],
  "buildPresets": [
    { "name": "pgo-gen", "configurePreset": "pgo-gen" },
    { "name": "pgo-use", "configurePreset": "pgo-use" }
  ],
  "testPresets": [
    {
      "name": "pgo-gen",
      "configurePreset": "pgo-gen",
      "filter": { "include": { "label": "performance" } }
    }
  ],
  "workflowPresets": [
    {
      "name": "pgo-gen",
      "steps": [
        { "type": "configure", "name": "pgo-gen" },
        { "type": "build", "name": "pgo-gen" },
        { "type": "test", "name": "pgo-gen" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "pgo-use",
      "steps": [
        { "type": "configure", "name": "pgo-use" },
        { "type": "build", "name": "pgo-use" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Basically what happens here is that we create two configure presets, `pgo-gen` and `pgo-use`, both of which have a common `base` they inherit from. This is just to show a technique for incrementally changing parts of cache variables using the environment as a side-channel.

Then we create two corresponding build presets and a test preset for pgo-gen that only runs the `performance`-labeled test cases.

Finally, we create two workflows to drive this. The end-to-end commands are:

```
$ cmake --workflow --preset pgo-gen
Executing workflow step 1 of 3: configure preset "pgo-gen"

Preset CMake variables:

  CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fprofile-generate"
  CMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fprofile-generate"

Preset environment variables:

  PGO_FLAGS="-fprofile-generate"

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done (6.3s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/alex/test/build

Executing workflow step 2 of 3: build preset "pgo-gen"

[2/2] Linking CXX executable example

Executing workflow step 3 of 3: test preset "pgo-gen"

Test project /home/alex/test/build
    Start 2: perf
1/1 Test #2: perf .............................   Passed    0.00 sec

100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 1

Label Time Summary:
performance    =   0.00 sec*proc (1 test)

Total Test time (real) =   0.00 sec
$ cmake --workflow --preset pgo-use
Executing workflow step 1 of 2: configure preset "pgo-use"

Preset CMake variables:

  CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fprofile-use"
  CMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fprofile-use"

Preset environment variables:

  PGO_FLAGS="-fprofile-use"

-- Configuring done (0.0s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/alex/test/build

Executing workflow step 2 of 2: build preset "pgo-use"

[2/2] Linking CXX executable example
```

And if I delete the build directory and try `pgo-use` without `gen`:

```
$ rm -rf build
$ Executing workflow step 1 of 2: configure preset "pgo-use"

Preset CMake variables:

  CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fprofile-use"
  CMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fprofile-use"

Preset environment variables:

  PGO_FLAGS="-fprofile-use"

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done (6.0s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/alex/test/build

Executing workflow step 2 of 2: build preset "pgo-use"

[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.cpp.o
/home/alex/test/main.cpp: In function ‘(static initializers for /home/alex/test/main.cpp)’:
/home/alex/test/main.cpp:5:1: warning: ‘/home/alex/test/build/CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.cpp.gcda’ profile count data file not found [-Wmissing-profile]
    5 | }
      | ^
[2/2] Linking CXX executable example
```

Then I'm missing the profile data as expected.

I initially wanted to write a single `pgo` workflow that consisted of all five steps, but sadly CMake currently doesn't allow two `configure` steps in a workflow. Why? I don't know. I'm going to open a bug report.

Comment: if you open a issue ticket, please add the link to your post :)

Comment: @starball - I will! It'll just take me a bit to write.

Comment: I'm not a fan of having to reconfigure in place. is that guaranteed to preserve all build artifacts from the gpo-gen buildsystem? if they're lost, it sounds like a great way to have a bunch of unnecessary build-work done in between changes... I know there are ways to point compilers at specific object file directories so that you can have two generated buildsystems.

Comment: CMake will not delete build artifacts upon reconfigure. I would reconfigure in place just because if you're using a generator (like Ninja) that correctly models dependencies on command line arguments, then rebuilding in place after updating the commands will exactly rebuild what's necessary.

Comment: Of course, a downside of the presented approach is that it's a bit "all or nothing". You could elaborate on this approach by introducing two cache variables: `PGO_TEST_ENABLE_PGO` and `PGO_TEST_PGO_FLAGS`. When the former is true, run `target_compile_options(example PRIVATE ${PGO_TEST_PGO_FLAGS})`. Then drive the compiler-specific PGO flags from the presets. You can get more complex by _detecting_ what the flags should be, but now I would say you're crossing the bridge into overengineering.

Comment: I'll also add that the modified approach plays well with `CMAKE_OPTIMIZE_DEPENDENCIES` and `CMAKE_LINK_DEPENDS_NO_SHARED`