# CMake: compile a program twice in a row

Tags: compilation, cmake, g++

To be able to do many automatic optimizations, I want to be able to compile my program using the flag `-fprofile-generate` first, then run it to generate the profile and then re-compile the program with `-fprofile-use` instead.

This means I want to compile my program twice in a row, with two different `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` each time.

How can I do that using CMake?

Comment: I have a GPL-licenced project where I have something that's kind of working for me. You can find it on github ([search for "okiidoku" on github](https://github.com/search?q=okiidoku)). You can also take a look at the LLVM firefox projects to see how they do things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build something and then run it and then build something else after execution by making use of customer targets and the "add_dependencies" command. For your gcov case you might do something like:

profile.cxx

```
#include <iostream>
int main(void) {
    std::cout << "Hello from Generating Profile run" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1 FATAL_ERROR)

project(profileExample C CXX)

# compile initial program
add_executable(profileGenerate profile.cxx)
set_target_properties(profileGenerate PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-fprofile-
generate")
target_link_libraries(profileGenerate gcov)

add_executable(profileUse profile.cxx)
set_target_properties(profileUse PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-fprofile-use")
target_link_libraries(profileUse gcov)

# custom target to run program
add_custom_target(profileGenerate_run
    COMMAND profileGenerate
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    COMMENT "run Profile Generate"
    SOURCES profile.cxx
    )

#create depency for profileUse on profileGenerate_run
add_dependencies(profileUse profileGenerate_run)
```

Output showing build -> run -> build

[image: Build Output]

Comment: `add_dependencies` wasn't sufficient for my own setup. Telling a target to build another target before itself is less than telling it that the sources depend on the outputs/byproducts of the target it depends on.

Comment: If you find that this solution doesn't make sources re-compile if the training data has changed, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42125009/11107541) and [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73574090/11107541).