# CMake's objects output folder variable

Tags: cmake

How "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeFiles/project.dir/", the place object files resulted from compilation will be placed on, can be un-hardcoded?

Going straightly to the problem, we have some tests that check objects resulted from compilation on harfbuzz cmake and we use a hardcoded string [there](https://github.com/harfbuzz/harfbuzz/blob/90f01bad637c8b1214f46d4df6d9552a6a728e29/CMakeLists.txt#L796) but that doesn't seem right and I hope some ${} or $<> exist for that.

Comment: Could you check what you get for `message("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}")`? I'm not sure anymore what is included `CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY`, but that's normally the path to CMake's intermediate directory.

Comment: Thanks Florian, I am evaluating your and Angew answers, your suggestion is in a correct direction but still no "project.dir", is there any hope for that also?

Comment: Just remembered having seen/answered a question about getting the list of target's object files before: [How to get path to object files with CMake for both multiconfiguration generator and makefile based ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884856/how-to-get-path-to-object-files-with-cmake-for-both-multiconfiguration-generator)

Comment: So I guess this should be marked as duplicate but on the meanwhile I upvoted you answer there at least :)

Comment: Thanks :-) I had another idea utilizing CMake's expansion rules. So would it be ok if it only works for makefile/Ninja generators?

Comment: That is also good to know. CMake is secondary build script on harfbuzz https://github.com/harfbuzz/harfbuzz/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt and I tried to make it on par with autotools solution. These tests can be ported to Windows someday but maybe not that soon. The main thing I wanted to know was if I have blindspot on finding object files which with your helps I reached to some conclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you're out of luck here. CMake keeps this as an internal implementation detail, by design.

I'd say it's unlikely to change, but if you want to be absolutely future-proof, you could use a workaround of creating a static library out of the object files and then manually unpacking it back into object files (using the appropriate archiver/librarian) as part of the test. If the object files are also used by another target, and linking to that static library wouldn't work for that target, you can make an [object library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) out of the files and then use that in both the original target and the for-test static library.

Here's an example of how you might achieve this workaround:

```
add_library(MyObjectLib OBJECT src/a.cpp src/b.cpp)

add_executable(Main src/main.cpp $<TARGET_OBJECTS:MyObjectLib>)

add_library(LibForTesting STATIC $<TARGET_OBJECTS:MyObjectLib>)

add_test(
  NAME check-static-inits.sh
  COMMAND ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/prepare-and-check-static-inits.sh $<TARGET_FILE:LibForTesting>
)
```

And here's what the script `prepare-and-check-static-inits.sh` would look like (pseudo-code):

```
ar -x $1 -o some_dir
./check-static-inits.sh some_dir
```

Comment: Thank you @Angew, I wanted to test your last idea, adding an object library target, but when I wanted to use $<TARGET_OBJECTS:hbobjs>, it was saying `The evaluation of the TARGET_OBJECTS generator expression is only suitable for consumption by CMake.  It is not suitable for writing out elsewhere.`, obviously what you was indicating also so there is not hope I guess on that solution also?

Comment: @EbrahimByagowi I've added an example of what I meant with using the static library. Can you compare it to what you did?

Comment: This looks complicated but great. I will see whether can I integrate it, thanks.

Comment: Your solution was great and I wrote this based on it https://github.com/harfbuzz/harfbuzz/pull/710#issuecomment-358372318 I am not applying that just right now till sometime to think and test it more

Answer (score 2):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

There is at the moment no variable or generator expression to get the list of object files used for linking a archive or library target.

But you could append compiler/archiver/linker calls with any program/script and utilize [CMake's expansion rules](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Build_Rules) inside those calls.

*Note*: That will only work CMake's [Command-Line Build Tool Generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#command-line-build-tool-generators). And the `list(APPEND ...)` calls only have to be there once in your CMake code after your `project()` call.

**Examples**

1. Generate a symbolic link to `<OBJECT_DIR>` with `<TARGET_NAME>`

   ```perl
   project(MyLib)

   list(
       APPEND CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_FINISH 
           "\"${CMAKE_COMMAND}\" -E create_symlink \"<OBJECT_DIR>\" \"<TARGET_NAME>\""
   )

   [...]

   add_library(MyLib STATIC src/a.cpp src/b.cpp)
   ```
2. Call some program to do something with the `<OBJECTS>` list (e.g. echo or write to a file)

   ```perl
   project(MyExe)

   list(
       APPEND CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE 
           "\"${CMAKE_COMMAND}\" -E echo \"<OBJECTS>\""
   )

   [...]

   add_executable(MyExe main.cpp)
   ```
3. Directly do something after each object file  is generated. In your case where you want to call `objdump` for each object file it would e.g. be:

   ```perl
   list(
       APPEND CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_OBJECT
           "${CMAKE_OBJDUMP} -t \"<OBJECT>\" > $(notdir <OBJECT>.dump)"
   )
   ```

   Unfortunately there is no expansion rule for "output file name" hence the platform/make specific trick with `$(notdir ...)`.

**References**

- [`CMAKE_<LANG>_ARCHIVE_FINISH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_ARCHIVE_FINISH.html)
- [`CMAKE_<LANG>_LINK_EXECUTABLE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_LINK_EXECUTABLE.html)
- [`CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILE_OBJECT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILE_OBJECT.html)
- [How to get path to object files with CMake for both multiconfiguration generator and makefile based ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884856/how-to-get-path-to-object-files-with-cmake-for-both-multiconfiguration-generator)