# How do I output the result of a generator expression in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I have the following simple CMake code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(PrintGenerators)

set(TEST_OR_GENERATOR "$<$<OR:0,0,1>:YAY!>")

message(STATUS ${TEST_OR_GENERATOR}) # Print out the result of the build
```

I expect this code to print out `YAY!`, but it does not. I instead get `$<$<OR:0,0,1>:YAY!>` as the output. How do I print the result of the evaluated generator expression during configuration?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> How do I print the result of the evaluated generator expression during configuration?

You cannot. Generator expressions are intended for things, which are not exactly known at configuration stage: they depend on build type, which, in case of multiconfiguration [generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-generators.7.html), becomes known only at the *build stage*.

You may, however, save a value of the generator expression into the file, but the file will be written only at the end of the configuration stage:

```
file(GENERATE OUTPUT <filename> CONTENT <string-with-generator-expression>)
```

More detailed description of `file(GENERATOR)` see in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/file.html#generate).

Answer (score 30):

You can add a custom command that echos the value at build time. This is how I did it when I needed it:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET mytarget POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo 
  "target dir = $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:mytarget>")
```

Comment: I was aware of this; the point of this question was to be able to print the value at configuration time.

Comment: What are the advantages of this answer over the accepted one?

Comment: Is it can print `$<CXX_COMPILER_ID>`?

Answer (score 12):

[From the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#debugging)

> Since generator expressions are evaluated during generation of the
> buildsystem, and not during processing of `CMakeLists.txt` files, it is
> not possible to inspect their result with the `message()` command.
>
> One possible way to generate debug messages is to add a custom target,
>
> ```
> add_custom_target(genexdebug COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "$<...>")
> ```
>
> The shell command `make genexdebug` (invoked after execution
> of `cmake`) would then print the result of `$<...>`.
>
> Another way is to write debug messages to a file:
>
> ```
> file(GENERATE OUTPUT filename CONTENT "$<...>")
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Since generator expressions are evaluated during generation of the buildsystem, and not during processing of `CMakeLists.txt` files, it is not possible to inspect their result with the `message()` command. One possible way to generate debug messages is to write debug messages to a file with `file(GENERATE)`:

```
file(GENERATE OUTPUT filename CONTENT "$<...>")
```

[reference](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html)