# How can I get a target's output-file's name during CMake's configuration phase (not the generation phase)?

Tags: cmake

I know we can use `$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:Foo>` to get the filename for `add_custom_command` and `add_custom_target` during build time, but I can't seem to find the answer on out how to get the filename during config time. For example,

```
add_library(Foo SHARED foo.cpp foo.h)
```

The best I get is `get_target_property(FOO_NAME Foo NAME)`, but `${FOO_NAME}` is `Foo`, what I want is something like `libFoo.so` or `libFoo.dylib` depends on the platform. How can we get the target file name during cmake config time?

For context on why I thought I initially thought I needed to be able to do this, see this other question: [In CMake how can I copy a target file to a custom location when target based generator expression for OUTPUT is not supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75415268/11107541).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't- at least- not covering all the possible scenarios. The way a output file name is constructed is complicated enough that you can only handle "simple" cases, and even doing that is complicated enough. I mean- look at all the things you have to handle, and the ways that they can override each other:

- [`variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html)
- [`prop_tgt/TYPE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/TYPE.html)
- [`prop_tgt/FRAMEWORK`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/FRAMEWORK.html)
- [`variable/CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX.html) and [`variable/CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX.html) and the language-specific overrides
- [`variable/CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX.html) and [`variable/CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX.html) and the language-specific overrides
- [`variable/CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_PREFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_PREFIX.html) and [`variable/CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_SUFFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_SUFFIX.html) and the language-specific overrides
- [`variable/CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX.html) and the language-specific overrides
- [`prop_tgt/OUTPUT_NAME`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/OUTPUT_NAME.html) and [`prop_tgt/OUTPUT_NAME_<CONFIG>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/OUTPUT_NAME_CONFIG.html)
- [`prop_tgt/ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_NAME`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_NAME.html) and [`prop_tgt/ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_NAME_<CONFIG>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_NAME_CONFIG.html)
- [`prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME.html) and [`prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME_<CONFIG>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME_CONFIG.html)
- [`prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_NAME`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_NAME.html) and [`prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_NAME_<CONFIG>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_NAME_CONFIG.html)

I believe you could do something like this:

```
# cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.x)
project(hello)
function(get_target_filename target outvar)
    set(outname "${target}")

    get_target_property(prop_outname "${target}" OUTPUT_NAME)
    if(NOT ("${prop_outname}" STREQUAL "prop_outname-NOTFOUND"))
        set(outname "${prop_outname}")
    endif()

    get_target_property(prop_cfg_outname "${target}" "${OUTPUT_NAME}_${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")
    if(NOT ("${prop_cfg_outname}" STREQUAL "prop_cfg_outname-NOTFOUND"))
        set(outname "${prop_cfg_outname}")
    endif()

    get_target_property(prop_archive_outname "${target}" ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_NAME)
    get_target_property(prop_library_outname "${target}" LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME)
    get_target_property(prop_runtime_outname "${target}" RUNTIME_OUTPUT_NAME)
    get_target_property(prop_archive_cfg_outname "${target}" "${ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_NAME}_${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")
    get_target_property(prop_library_cfg_outname "${target}" "${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME}_${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")
    get_target_property(prop_runtime_cfg_outname "${target}" "${RUNTIME_OUTPUT_NAME}_${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")
    if(NOT ("${prop_archive_cfg_outname}" STREQUAL "prop_archive_cfg_outname-NOTFOUND"))
        set(prop_archive_outname "${prop_archive_cfg_outname}")
    endif()
    if(NOT ("${prop_library_cfg_outname}" STREQUAL "prop_library_cfg_outname-NOTFOUND"))
        set(prop_library_outname "${prop_library_cfg_outname}")
    endif()
    if(NOT ("${prop_runtime_cfg_outname}" STREQUAL "prop_runtime_cfg_outname-NOTFOUND"))
        set(prop_runtime_outname "${prop_runtime_cfg_outname}")
    endif()


    get_target_property(prop_type "${target}" TYPE)
    get_target_property(prop_is_framework "${target}" FRAMEWORK)
    if("${prop_is_framework}")
        set(filename "${outname}")
    elseif(prop_type STREQUAL "STATIC_LIBRARY")
        if(NOT ("${prop_archive_outname}" STREQUAL "prop_archive_outname-NOTFOUND"))
            set(outname "${prop_archive_outname}")
        endif()
        set(prefix "${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX}")
        set(suffix "${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}")
    elseif(prop_type STREQUAL "MODULE_LIBRARY")
        if(NOT ("${prop_library_outname}" STREQUAL "prop_library_outname-NOTFOUND"))
            set(outname "${prop_library_outname}")
        endif()
        set(prefix "${CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_LIBRARY_PREFIX}")
        set(suffix "${CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}")
    elseif(prop_type STREQUAL "SHARED_LIBRARY")
        if(WIN32)
            if(NOT ("${prop_runtime_outname}" STREQUAL "prop_runtime_outname-NOTFOUND"))
                set(outname "${prop_runtime_outname}")
            endif()
        else()
            if(NOT ("${prop_library_outname}" STREQUAL "prop_library_outname-NOTFOUND"))
                set(outname "${prop_library_outname}")
            endif()
        endif()
        set(prefix "${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX}")
        set(suffix "${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}")
    elseif(prop_type STREQUAL "EXECUTABLE")
        if(NOT ("${prop_runtime_outname}" STREQUAL "prop_runtime_outname-NOTFOUND"))
            set(outname "${prop_runtime_outname}")
        endif()
        set(prefix "${CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_PREFIX}")
        set(suffix "${CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX}")
    else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "target \"${target}\" is not of type STATIC_LIBRARY, MODULE_LIBRARY, SHARED_LIBRARY, or EXECUTABLE.")
    endif()

    get_target_property(prop_prefix "${target}" PREFIX)
    if(NOT ("${prop_prefix}" STREQUAL "prop_prefix-NOTFOUND"))
        set(prefix "${prop_prefix}")
    endif()
    get_target_property(prop_suffix "${target}" PREFIX)
    if(NOT ("${prop_suffix}" STREQUAL "prop_suffix-NOTFOUND"))
        set(suffix "${prop_suffix}")
    endif()

    set("${outvar}" "${prefix}${outname}${suffix}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
add_library(static_lib STATIC test.cpp)
add_library(shared_lib SHARED test.cpp)
add_executable(executable test.cpp)
get_target_filename(static_lib static_lib_filename)
get_target_filename(shared_lib shared_lib_filename)
get_target_filename(executable executable_filename)
message(STATUS "static_lib_filename: ${static_lib_filename}")
message(STATUS "shared_lib_filename: ${shared_lib_filename}")
message(STATUS "executable_filename: ${executable_filename}")
```

The above is a basic implementation. I got too lazy to handle language-specific overrides, and it doesn't handle some (perhaps important) nuances like:

- The fact that **most of those target properties can themselves have generator expressions in them** (see their docs), which, if it happens to you, I think you're out of luck.
- The fact that **`CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is only relevant for single-config generators- not multi-config generators.**
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX_LANG.html
- Other language-specific overrides like `CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX_<LANG>`

You'd need to check if those exist and handle them if they do... except in honesty I'm not quite sure how, given that it doesn't seem like targets have a `LANGUAGE` property. [Source files do](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/LANGUAGE.html), but that's not what we need here. One might need to go to [the CMake Discourse to ask about this](https://discourse.cmake.org/).

Note: If you want the full *path* to the target output file... oh boy...

- [`prop_tgt/ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) and [`prop_tgt/ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_<CONFIG>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_CONFIG.html)
- [`prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) and [`prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_<CONFIG>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_CONFIG.html)
- [`prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) and [`prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_<CONFIG>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_CONFIG.html)

More fun notes: If you want to evaluate generator expressions recursively at generation time (for generator expressions that themselves evaluate to generator expressions), you can use [the `$<GENEX_EVAL:...>` generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:GENEX_EVAL), but of course- that doesn't apply to this question, which is about configure time.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit clumsy but the file name can be constructed in the following way:

```
set(FOO_NAME "${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX}Foo${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}")
```

See also [cmake doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX.html).

Note that the two variables will be overridden by the respective `CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_??FIX_<LANG>` variables. So if that's a possibility, you need make sure you catch the right variable.

Let me add the final remark that the rationale behind CMake is *you don't need to know*. CMake operates on targets, not files. So whatever you're trying to achieve might be possible without getting the filename.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't work if we don't know whether the library is static or dynamic beforehand.

Comment: @user3667089 that's true. I assumed you would know as much and my lightweight, one line solution would suffice. Luckily, user spelled out a whole function in their answer.