# CMake generator expressions, but evaluated at configure time

Tags: cmake

I'm working with a CMake body of code that wants to set certain variables with [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html), e.g., the second entry in

```
target_sources( date-tz
  PUBLIC
    include/date/tz.h
    $<$<BOOL:${IOS}>:include/date/ios.h>
)
```

The idea here is: if `${IOS}` is `TRUE`, then the second line expands to

```
include/date/ios.h
```

and otherwise to nothing (`""`).
This however is not true: The output target files will contain something like

```
$<$<BOOL:TRUE>:include/date/ios.h>
```

I gather from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51353286/353337) that generator expressions are for things that are *not* known at configure time, and hence are probably not what we actually want.

One alternative would be to set

```
if (${IOS})
   set(ios_h include/date/ios.h)
else()
   set(ios_h "")
endif()

target_sources( date-tz
  PUBLIC
    include/date/tz.h
    ${ios_h}
)
```

which sure enough is evaluated at configure time. Is this the correct approach? Is there a shorter (inline) form of the latter?

This is with CMake 3.16.3.

Comment: What cmake version are you running?

Comment: @digby280 CMake 3.16.3. I've updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the correct approach?

Approach, yes. But don't expand IOS, `if` handles that. Just:

```
if (IOS)
   target_sources(date-tz PUBLIC include/date/ios.h)
endif()
```

> Is there a shorter (inline) form of the latter?

You can write a macro.

> I gather from here that generator expressions are for things that are not known at configure time, and hence are probably not what we actually want.

Personally, I would say: neee, use the way is most readable to you. I would say using a generator expression here is perfectly fine. (But I guess if someone uses a IDE that searches headers from cmake, it may have problems? I don't know, never used such IDEs).

> The idea here is: if ${IOS} is TRUE

That sounds strange, [`IOS` should be set to `1`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/IOS.html?highlight=ios). So no need for `$<BOOL`, just:

```
$<${IOS}:include/date/ios.h>
```

There is also `$<PLATFORM_ID` that you can use, that allows for a comma separated list of platforms, I guess that would be along:

```
$<$<PLATFORM_ID:iOS>:include/date/ios.h>
```

Comment: Can I call `target_sources` multiple times, and it simply adds the sources?

Comment: From my memory, yes, it "adds sources to a target".