# Setting a cmake variable based on build configuration (Debug/Release), where am I going wrong?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am new to cmake and having a lot of fun. I want a variable to contain a path, depending on whether or not I am in a debug or release configuration. My code looks like this:

```
set( LIBRARY_DIR
    $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>: "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/debug">
    $<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/release">) # Directory is debug/release dependent
message (STATUS "Directory is ${LIBRARY_DIR}")
```

However, the message I get out is surprising:

```
Directory is $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:;C:/path/lib/debug;>;$<$<CONFIG:Release>:"C:/path/lib/release"
```

It's as though my generators aren't getting resolved at all, and are being interpreted as string literals. This seems weird to me, but as I said, I'm new to cmake and this is all strange to me. Have I made any obvious mistakes?

Comment: @drescherjm If so, any reasons why the message I get back doesn't have the resolved path, but the literal strings for the generators?

Comment: @drescherjm Yeah, it sure seems that way. Is there a way to print out the final result instead of the internals?

Comment: I erased my comment because I am not 100% sure.

Comment: @drescherjm Yeah, I actually think you're incorrect. Pretty sure it's pulling all of that into the variable.

Comment: As an update, I did find a thread describing the same problem. Apparently, generators do not get evaluated until the build stage. I'm wondering if it is still possible to use generators the way I want (to build a library path), but it is not the way I'm currently doing it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51353110/how-do-i-output-the-result-of-a-generator-expression-in-cmake/51353286

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Upon second look, not what I originally wrote.

Your problem is with writing the arguments. You'd better checkout the [command_arguments](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#command-arguments) section of `cmake-language` doc.

Your problem is with how you write the arguments. As a result, tokens that cmake lexer gets is quite different from what you actually wishes. You should use so-called `quoted argument` or `bracket argument` to binding the generator expression as a whole.

---

Another problem is with the time of evaluation.

This is because generators are evaluated at generation step. Please refer to the [Debugging](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#debugging) section of `cmake-generator-expression` documentation.

```
add_custom_target(genexdebug COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "$<...>")

### OR

file(GENERATE OUTPUT filename CONTENT "$<...>")
```