# CMake: output the result of a generator expression that cannot be used with add_custom_target or file()?

Tags: c++, debugging, cmake

I found both [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51353110/how-do-i-output-the-result-of-a-generator-expression-in-cmake) and [this documentation entry](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#debugging) advising users to "debug" generator expressions by either using the `add_custom_target()` command or the `file(GENERATE)` command.

However, say you have a `CMakeLists.txt` like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(Toy VERSION 1.0)

set(gcc_like_cxx "$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,ARMClang,AppleClang,Clang,GNU,LCC>")
set(msvc_like_cxx "$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,MSVC>")
```

and you now want to check for the value of `gcc_like_cxx`. Well, according to the documentation, something like

```
file(GENERATE OUTPUT hahaha CONTENT ${gcc_like_cxx})
```

or

```
add_custom_target(genexdebug COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "${gcc_like_cxx}")
```

could be done, but either of the two produces the same error:

```
  $<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:lang,id> may only be used with binary targets to
  specify include directories, compile definitions, and compile options.  It
  may not be used with the add_custom_command, add_custom_target, or
  file(GENERATE) commands.
```

Is there a way to get the value of the generator expression if the expression may not be used with the "standard" debugging options?

Comment: `COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID` doesn't make sense outside of a target, not sure there's much you can do

Comment: @AlanBirtles But could we perhaps trigger an output in the build step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to use the `target` argument in `file(GENERATE)` in CMake version `3.19`.
2. You need to add variable prefix to the output file or there will be following error:

```bash
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  Evaluation file to be written multiple times with different content.  This
  is generally caused by the content evaluating the configuration type,
  language, or location of object files:
    
    /home/user/build/hahaha
```

I run the following CMake file on my server and it works:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)

project(Toy VERSION 1.0)

set(gcc_like_cxx "$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,ARMClang,AppleClang,Clang,GNU,LCC>")
set(msvc_like_cxx "$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,MSVC>")

file(GENERATE OUTPUT "${gcc_like_cxx}/log.txt" CONTENT "${gcc_like_cxx}\n" TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME})

add_executable(Toy toy.c)
```

[CMake Gitlab --
file(GENERATE): Add TARGET argument](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/5131)

[GitHub issue -- As a result, I added the TARGET argument to file(GENERATE) in CMake 3.19](https://github.com/facebook/folly/issues/1414#issuecomment-683258499)

Comment: I see. Thanks! This is weird for two reasons. One, the CMake Error that I initially got specifically said that what I tried is impossible (It said "$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:lang,id> [...] may not be used with [...] file(GENERATE) command."). But that's just bad documentation I guess. But second, I don't really understand... why does this solution produce *two* output files?

Comment: Generator expressions are evaluated during build system generation to produce information specific to each build configuration [cmake-generator-expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#introduction). There are **two** output files because the `gcc_like_cxx` expression yields two different build configurations.

You can try deleting the `GNU` in the first `set` command and you may get only one (which is `0` on my server) output, which means the compiler on my server does not match anyone in the `ARMClang,AppleClang,Clang,LCC` list.